# Trackpad problems (scrolling)

Tags: touchpad

I have a Razer Blade Pro (2014 - has a "fancy" trackpad). It's "registering" as a mouse (the pointer speed isn't changing the trackpad settings, but rather from the mouse settings). I can't scroll (tried using edge, and double finger). Can anyone help me out? (P.S. I'm pretty new to Linux. Just installed the OS today.)

Answer (score 1):

As I remember, you can set it in *System Settings>Mouse and Touchpad*.
By default elementary has no scrolling and tap to click on touchpad, so you need to enable that there :)

Comment: Thanks. I had already tried that, but it still didn't work.